# h2 wrapping to left instead of center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `<h2>` tag that is wrapping when the window gets smaller. I want the text to be in the center but it's currently wrapping and ends up as a paragraph on the left side. I am using flexbox `align-items: center` so it should be centered or am I missing something?

[Here is a snippet](https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/RQGRME)

Comment: `align-items` center the element, not its content, and the dupe explains/shows that with a border, to better _see_ what goes on.

Comment: Thank you! That other answer fixed it :)